# Parallelize preorder tree

Tags: java, akka, executorservice

I want to modify or clone/transform items in a preorder sorted List of tree items in parallel. That is the list traversal starts at a random item in the list and denotes a subtree-traversal (depth, parent-pointer, descendantSize and angleStart/angleEnd is available for a radial view).

My code currently looks like:

```
items = ((AbsModel<SunburstContainer, SunburstItem>)model).listIterator(pHitItemIndex);
items.next();
for (int i = pHitItemIndex + 1; i < endIndex && items.hasNext(); i++) {
  final SunburstItem oldChild = items.next();
  final SunburstItem newChild = new SunburstItem(oldChild);
  final float newStartAngle =
    (oldChild.getAngleStart() - oldRoot.getAngleStart()) * angleFactor;
  LOGWRAPPER.debug("angleStart: " + newStartAngle);
  newChild.setAngleStart(newStartAngle);
  float newEndAngle =
    (oldChild.getAngleEnd() - oldChild.getAngleStart()) * angleFactor
     + newChild.getAngleStart();
  LOGWRAPPER.debug("angleEnd: " + newEndAngle);
  if (newEndAngle > PConstants.TWO_PI) {
    newEndAngle = PConstants.TWO_PI;
  }
  newChild.setAngleEnd(newEndAngle);
  newChild.setAngleCenter(newChild.getAngleStart()
    + ((newChild.getAngleEnd() - newChild.getAngleStart()) / 2f));
  newChild.setIndexToParent(oldChild.getIndexToParent() - pHitItemIndex);
  int newDepth = 0;
  LOGWRAPPER.debug("child depth: " + oldChild.getDepth());
  LOGWRAPPER
    .debug("parent depth: " + model.getItem(oldChild.getIndexToParent()).getDepth());
  final int parentDepth = model.getItem(oldChild.getIndexToParent()).getDepth();
  if ((parentDepth + 1) != oldChild.getDepth()) {
    newDepth = oldDepthMax + 2;
  } else {
    newDepth = newItems.get(newChild.getIndexToParent()).getDepth() + 1;
  }
  if (newDepth > depthMax) {
    depthMax = newDepth;
  }
  LOGWRAPPER.debug("newDepth: " + newDepth);
  newChild.setDepth(newDepth);
  newChild.update(mMappingMode, mBuffer);
  newItems.add(newChild);
}
```

I think about simply partitioning the (sub)list, that is [pHitItemIndex + 1, endIndex] into different parts and submit Callables to an ExecutorService. Currently the whole algorithm is executed in a Callable submitted to an ExecutorService, but I assume I can also simply submit partitions/Callables to the same ExecutorService. I wonder if I would gain any advantage of using actors for instance using Akka, or using the ForkJoin framework.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a problem where Parallel Collections in Scala could help out.

Comment: Thanks, but on a second thought it seems it's not really parallelizable, as I need the transformed parent item for a depth calculation :-/